# Trying to upload files to sharepoint using REST API ,Python using Postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, postman, python

```
import requests

url = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/QE/Shared%20Documents/_api/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('product-xxxxx-metrics/xxxxx-dashboard-automation')/Files/add(url='test.csv',overwrite=true)"

payload=""
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSIsImtpZCI6IjJaUXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxHhZTkdqUhY0TKfWD6PsoOo2SM8Q',
  'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
  'Host': 'axtria.sharepoint.com'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data= payload)

print(response.text)
```

Hi,
I am using this code snippet to upload files on sharepoint using Python and this I have done using Postman Tool.
I am getting no error but the file is also not getting uploaded on the specific location.
Would really appreciate if anybody could help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the file contents in the payload,

I answered something similar some time ago,

[Bad Request for URL- 400](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305056/bad-request-for-url-400/305059#305059)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reverting. In the payload can I add my file which needs to be uploaded from the local system?