# Bad Request for URL- 400

Tags: python

400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:

```
https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/QE/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/product-health-metrics')/Files/add(overwrite=true,url='C:/Users/A5553/Downloads/XXXXX-salesiq-ce-iqs-open-20221130.csv
```

Receiving this error while trying to upload files to SharePoint. I am not able to resolve the issue.

Can somebody please tell me how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write using a local file, like, C:/Users/A5553/Downloads/XXXXX-salesiq-ce-iqs-open-20221130.csv,
this just needs to be FILENAME.extension, and then followed by the content of the file in bytes array.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

From the official MS Documentation,

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Content-Length: {length of request body as integer}
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"

"Contents of file"


function getBuffer(resolve) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
    reader.onload = function() {
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result
      var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      resolve(bytes);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reverting. But I am yet not clear with the fact of how to add the content of file?

Comment: Hi, I could not follow up how to add the content of the files

Comment: Hi, @Kompal, I added a function to read bytes from a file array